# How do I launch my website online?

Tags: web-hosting

I designed my website on Dreamweaver. Then I bought a domain name. What do I need to do now to launch my website online?

Comment: You have to get a webhoster or a vps.

Comment: You can decide which hosting to use. Both [amazon](http://aws.amazon.com) and [google](http://appengine.google.com) offer free-tier alternatives for small-scale websites. On amazon you can get a server for free with their AWS and at google you could use the gae (google app engine).